# setting default umask and user:group on directory

Tags: permissions, chmod, acl, umask

I have a directory `data` and I need to set default `umask` and ownership for all directories/files (both existing and future files).

I want all files in `data` to have ownership `root:martin` ans permissions `750/640`

I am aware that I can use `setfacl` to set default `umask` recursively using

```
setfacl -R -d -m o::--- data
```

and that I can use `setgid` bit on the directory, so that all created files have ownership `root:martin`

```
chmod -R +s data
```

## UPDATE

Even with `setfacl` rules and `setgid` described above, this  still does not work completely. I am trying to achieve the following:

When root creates new directories/files:

1. the ownership should be `root:martin`
2. the permissions should be `750/640`

I have `setgid` and `acl` permissions set on current directory:

```
$ getfacl .
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::---
```

When I create new directories or files with `mkdir/touch`, everything works as I want to.

But when I copy files with or directories with `cp` or `scp`, then the ownership is correct, but the permissions are wrong, in a peculiar way. Example:

```
$ ll /tmp/ZZ/
-rw------- 1 martin martin 0  2021-Sep-15  05:27  aa
-rw-r--r-- 1 martin martin 0  2021-Sep-15  05:27  bb
```

When I copy these files as root to my dir, the permission on one file is correct, the other is wrong:

```
# cp /tmp/ZZ/* .
ll
-rw------- 1 root martin 0  2021-Sep-15  05:29  aa
-rw-r----- 1 root martin 0  2021-Sep-15  05:29  bb
```

Why does this not work as desired?

Comment: I don't think it would be superior in any way other then it's 1 cmd. vs. 2.

Comment: AFAIK, umask is only per-process, not per-directory. Only ACLs are associated with directories.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: The permissions of the files inside the directory doesn't matter, blocking at the directory level is usually enough, so `chmod 2750 /path-to-dir` is enough.

Option 2: Use ACLs only (`chmod 2750 /path-to-dir` is not necessary, but make things nicer for people not used to ACLs).

```
setfacl -R -b -d -m o::--- -m u::rwX -m g::rX  .
```

note that you could set `g::rwX` to achieve 770/660